# How to prevent from [(NgModel)] that's being applied to all other input fields?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm a little bit confused about what to use other than [(ngModel)]. As you can below the code snippet and images provided, ngModel binding is being applied to all other input fields when I click on the Edit button because of *NgFor. Could you guys please recommend me some suggestions?

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tH3P.png)

```html
Below is cart component template.

<div class="container my-5">
    <h1>Your Cart</h1>
       <div *ngFor="let item of listAlbums" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h6>Item name: {{item.title}}</h6>
                    <img src="{{item.thumbnailUrl}}">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" value="{{item.quantity}}">
                    <button (click)="remove(item)" class="btn btn-danger mx-3">X</button>
                    <button (click)="edit(item)" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="{{item.title}}" [(ngModel)]="newTitle" [hidden]="!hideEdit">
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

```html
  
Below is the cart component.

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.scss']
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
  listAlbums:Album[]=[]
  hideEdit:boolean=false
  newTitle:string;
  constructor(private productService:ProductService) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.itemList.subscribe(data=>
      {this.listAlbums = data })
  }
  remove(item:Album) {
    this.productService.removeItem(item)
  }
  edit(item:Album) {
    this.hideEdit = !this.hideEdit
    this.productService.editItem(item, this.newTitle)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an array and bind it to ngModel

```
<div class="container my-5">
    <h1>Your Cart</h1>
       <div *ngFor="let item of listAlbums; let i = index" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h6>Item name: {{item.title}}</h6>
                    <img src="{{item.thumbnailUrl}}">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" value="{{item.quantity}}">
                    <button (click)="remove(item)" class="btn btn-danger mx-3">X</button>
                    <button (click)="edit(item)" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="{{item.title}}" [(ngModel)]="newTitle[i]" [hidden]="!hideEdit">
                </div>
            </div>
</div>

newTitle = Array(listAlbums.length); // it will create an array of specific length.
```

This way you can bind all the inputs to specific array instance separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to edit the title of individual items in cart, then bind to that item's title directly instead of updating the same string(newTitle) for all.
Use [(ngModel)] = "item.title" in

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{item.title}}" [(ngModel)]="item.title" [hidden]="!hideEdit">
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it already. Let's say I have 8 items in my cart. When I click on the edit button, all 8 inputs are enabled at the same time.

Comment: That is because you have used the same var hideEdit for all inputs, try passing index to edit func: use `*ngFor="let item of listAlbums; let i = index"` `(click)="edit(item,i)"` and use hideEdit as array to update like this `[hidden]="!hideEdit[i]"`